# swift get the contents of CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I am making a freehand drawing on a CAShapeLayer over an UIView and I need to keep the contents of that layer in a variable so that I can redraw it when segue happens back to this viewController. How do I get the contents of a CAShapeLayer()

```
let drawingLayer = CAShapeLayer()
drawingLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
drawingLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
imgView.layer.insertSublayer(drawingLayer, at: 1)
```

I need something like this when the navigation happen back to this controller

```
//drawingLayer.contents = someStoredContents
```

Comment: What do you mean "contents"? Do you just want to store the `CAShapeLayer` as a property so you can access it later?

Comment: I know that `CAShapeLayer`s have a `contents` property that's an array of `Any`, but I guess what I'm asking is what you need to do with it?

Comment: ah sorry! to be so naive, all I had to do is to get is drawingLayer.path. Just got that, thanks for your time